# Get a queryset value in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

How can I get the value of this queryset?

I'm trying to get the value of name but it only show object.

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)

class SubBrand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand)

>>> print Brand.objects.filter(subbrand__id='2')
<QuerySet [<Brand: Brand object>]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use index

```
Brand.objects.filter(subbrand__id='2')[0].name
```